# Error: Query.get failed: First argument must be an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestor on React Native.

I am getting this error:

> Error: Query.get failed: First argument must be an object

When I try to fetch User data from other collection(Item), but that would not work.

```
export const itemsFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('items').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const items = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      return items
   })
    .then((items) => {
      const userPromises = items.map((item, itemId)  => {
        const userId = item.userId;
        console.log('userId: ', userId);
        return firebase.firestore().collection('users').get(userId)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('snapshot:', snapshot);
        const user = snapshot.docs.data();
        return user;
        console.log('user:', user);
      })
      .then(user => ({...item, user: user, itemId}));
      });
      dispatch({ type: 'ui/loading/hide' });
      return Promise.all(userPromises);
    })
  };
};
```

I could get data `snapshot` but I cannot realize still.

Answer (score 2):

get() doesn't take an argument like this:

```
return firebase.firestore().collection('users').get(userId)
```

If you want to fetch a document by ID, you need to build a DocumentReference using [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), and call get() on it:

```
return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()
```

That will return a promise the yields a single DocumentSnapshot with the contents of that document.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the other error `TypeError: relativePath.split is not a function` occurs. And I'm trying to get dabatase key = userId.

Answer (score 2):

See [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/QuerySnapshot) documentation. The `.where` is optional.

```
let query = firestore.collection('col').where('foo', '==', 'bar');

query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
  let docs = querySnapshot.docs;
  for (let doc of docs) {
    console.log(`Document found at path: ${doc.ref.path}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP isn't using a where clause anyway.

Comment: ...it was simply in the documentation. it's optional. Concept/Code example should provide him what he needs though.